# Using Thrift C++ Library in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, thrift

I want to use the Thrift 0.8.0 c++ library in Xcode. Therefore I configured thrift with

```
./configure --without-java --without-python --without-ruby --without-php --enable-static
```

I dragged the static library into my project. Then I set the "Header Search Paths" to "/usr/local/include/thrift" and "/opt/local/include" (because i installed boost with via macports).

I can run the Thrift Server as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC++)

When I try to run the client it throws several errors.

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h

```
 sockaddr* getCachedAddress(socklen_t* len) const;
```

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:216:3: error: unknown type name 'sockaddr'

```
void setCachedAddress(const sockaddr* addr, socklen_t len);
```

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:216:30: error: unknown type name 'socklen_t'

```
void setCachedAddress(const sockaddr* addr, socklen_t len);
```

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:237:31: error: unknown type name 'sockaddr'

```
 void setCachedAddress(const sockaddr* addr, socklen_t len);
```

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:237:47: error: unknown type name 'socklen_t'

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:290:5: error: unknown type name 'sockaddr_in'

```
  union {
sockaddr_in ipv4;
sockaddr_in6 ipv6;
} cachedPeerAddr_;
```

/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:291:5: error: unknown type name 'sockaddr_in6'

```
boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
```

.../ThriftClient/ThriftClient/Something_client.cpp
.../ThriftClient/ThriftClient/Something_client.cpp:15:49:{15:68-15:74}: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'apache::thrift::transport::TBufferedTransport' [3]

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

After including in TSocket.h the following lines everything works fine.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: Have you done a Google search for some of the error or types? First entry when searching for "socklen_t" was the actual header file you need for that type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found the missing includes for TSocket.h . On the mac for socklen_t and sockaddr you have to #include <sys/socket.h>, for sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6 its #include <arpa/inet.h>.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <thrift/config.h>
```

or just

```
#define HAVE_CONFIG_H 1
```